# C# Pattern for process management

Tags: c#, state

I hope this question isn't too open ended, but basically I need to create a program that can manage processes. The processing that will be done will contain a number of steps that take long to complete (generating reports, and emailing them out etc).

Method signatures for managing the process would look something like:

```
    int StartProcess(string inputData)
    {
        return Process.Start();
    }

    bool Pause(int processId)
    {
        return false;
    }

    bool ResumeProcess(int processId)
    {
        return false;
    }

    string GetProcessStatus(int processId)
    {
        return "running";
    }
```

The Part I cant quite get my head around is how I'd manage the State of the process (multiple processes need top be able to be run at once).

Is the best way to do something like this to store state information in a database and then update a state field as each step in the process is completed? Is a database table necessary?

Are there any free 3rd party libraries that could me implement something like this? I assume its quite a common problem.

Something like K2 blackpearl or another workflow application without the fancy user interface...

Comment: Have you checked Windows Workflow Foundation (WF 4.5)?

Comment: I believe you should look at [Workflow Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/jj684582.aspx)

Comment: nope haven't heard of that...will do some reading up on it now quick

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on your requirements.

If you need to manage long-running processes, or processes that can survive a computer reboot, then obviously you will need to store process and state information in a database.

You also need to define what happens when a process is paused. Is it paused immediately, or does it finish its current step first? If it is stopped immediately, does it store its state so that, if it is resumed only after a reboot, it can continue where it left off? etc....

Basically you could say that every process would run on its own thread, and your process manager should thus manage those threads, and offer a uniform way to processes to store their state.

In all, we can't say much more if we don't know your requirements.